# Ad mobs or iAd?

Tags: android, ios, admob, iad, ads

Hi i'm developing app using native SDKs on android / ios building free app and want to include ads and want to use same revenue stream from either one of the provider so i'm not chasing seperately for payments etc...

i know ad mobs has ios / android interface but downside for ios is per google admob section

The very first time AdMob sees your publisher ID it may take up to two minutes to receive an ad. This initial two minute lag will recur every time the app goes unused for 24 hours.

This is not good as delay is not nice for UI so from dev submission and development purpose

- which one is cross comptabile?
- which one is better in revenew?
- High eCPM?
- which are easy and fast to imimplement?
- using one of the other competitor will it cause rejection from android store or apple store upon submission?
- ads company release payment cycle shortest and fastest?

any light shed here will be very helpful or any other compatible ones which wont get rejected from app store submission will also do fine as long as they dont cause obstruction in app usage.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find the answers to most of your questions at the web sites for the two services:

- [www.admob.com](http://www.admob.com/)
- [developer.apple.com/iad](http://developer.apple.com/iad/)

In a nutshell, you can display AdMob ads in your iOS app, but iAd is specific to iOS -- you can't currently display iAd ads in Android apps. I doubt that using AdMob in your iOS app would be grounds for rejection from Apple's app store -- many, many apps already do this. As for revenue, ease of implementation, payment info... experiences vary, but both are fairly easy to use, both pay developers often enough that may developers use them.

Comment: Good answer for good question in my opinion.